# Does the Holy Sprit prevent one from praying for those to whom the intended prayer is of no use?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, spirit

We read in Jn 11:5-6 (NRSVCE):

> Accordingly, though Jesus loved Martha and her sister and Lazarus, after having heard that Lazarus was ill, he stayed two days longer in the place where he was.

We also read in Mark 5:

> Then one of the synagogue leaders, named Jairus, came, and when he saw Jesus, he fell at his feet.  He pleaded earnestly with him, “My little daughter is dying. Please come and put your hands on her so that she will be healed and live.” So Jesus went with him........ While Jesus was still speaking, some people came from the house of Jairus, the synagogue leader. “Your daughter is dead,” they said. “Why bother the teacher anymore?” Overhearing what they said, Jesus told him, “Don’t be afraid; just believe.”

In both cases, Jesus recuses himself from praying for the persons (Lazarus and Jairus'daughter) while they are alive, knowing well that they are destined to die once.

I have had some personal experiences when I forgot to pray for the physical well-being of some relatives, and would realize my forgetfulness only when they would suddenly die ! Occasionally, when I pray for the recovery of someone taken  seriously ill at a far-away place, the prayer somehow turns into a prayer for the  soul, before  I am told of his/her death!

Now, we believe in the intervention of Holy Spirit in our prayers, that He  channelizes them.

My question therefore,  is: **According to Catholic scholars, does the Holy Sprit prevent one from praying for those, to whom the intended prayer is of no use?**

Comment: "Jesus recuses himself from praying for the persons" I don't see anything in the text that says this. Where are you getting this idea from?

Comment: True, the scriptures do not say so; but the chronology of events gives the hint. For instance, Jesus could immediately have rushed to Bethany to heal Lazarus before the latter would die.

Comment: Jesus praying and Jesus departing are completely independent things. One does not prevent or require the other.

Comment: The question would be improved by removing the "*I have had …*" personal paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, Ray Butterworth. My narration is based on personal experience. At the age of 15,   I  memorized  a list of  all my relatives and started praying for their well-being. Over a period of time,  quite inadvertently I missed the name of Uncle Paul from the list. I realized the omission only   when Uncle Paul died in an accident in September, 1977. I will be the last to assume that he died because I had stopped praying for him. But I had all the reason to believe that God had wanted to me not to lose my trust in prayer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Does the Holy Sprit prevent one from praying for those to whom the intended prayer is of no use?**

The short answer is **no**.

There is no Catholic teaching that states the Holy Sprit prevents one from praying for those to whom the intended prayer is of no use. The traditional point of view is that God will apply such prayers to another souls so that prayer will used effectively, although we may never know who profits from it.

This is how such things were explained to me while in the seminary.

Prayer in this sense for someone is never in vain!

Comment: Thanks, Ken Graham . It is really heartening to hear from you the  traditional point of view   ` that God will apply such prayers to other souls so that prayer will used effectively, although we may never know who profits from it. '  Hope the point of view becomes part of day-to-day catechism. The readers would be benefited if you can also quote a reference of two from the scriptures in support.